# usb external storage on router modem

Tags: router, wireless-router, adsl

I've a router modem that has an usb connection , I can connect external hard drive or memory cards to it and share it over the network .

it works fine and I've no problem with this . the only issue is this ,I have to disable dhcp in my route,I cannot enable it beacuse of some problems that I would have.

When the dhcp is disable, I get ip addresses like 192.168.60.x , the range is 60 for example .

when It gets this range , I could not access my usb external storage , usb storage is availbe when I have an Ip address like this 192.168.1.x , when the ip is in range 1 , I can access my external storage .

the question is , is there any way that I can get ip address in range 1 despite dhcp is off ? or any other way that I can access my external storage ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to disable the router's DHCP server and assign its LAN side a fixed IP addresses that is inside the subnet your LAN uses but outside the main router's DHCP range.

So, for example, if your main router is 192.168.60.1 and its DHCP range is .100 through .200, you could assign this device 192.168.60.2